Why isn't the FFT being plotted?
I am working on a spectrum analyzer. I've gotten to the point that the time domain of my signal is being plotted but I get no result for the FFT. I've added print statements to check whether or not I am actually getting real values within the expected range, and it looks like I'm getting real results. The frequency plot seems like it's just plotting zero. I can't really tell what I'm doing wrong can someone help me?
Code:
import pyaudio
import struct
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.animation as animation
from scipy.fftpack import fft

CHUNK = 1024 * 2  # Defines the chunk size, i.e., the number of audio samples per frame that will be displayed.
FORMAT = pyaudio.paInt16 # Defines the audio format as 16-bit integers.
CHANNELS = 1  #  Defines the number of audio channels (mono sound).
RATE = 44100  #  Defines the sampling rate, i.e., the number of samples per second.

p = pyaudio.PyAudio()  # Creates a PyAudio object, which serves as the main interface for accessing audio I/O functionalities.

# Opens an audio stream for both input and output, specifying the format, channels, 
# sampling rate, and chunk size.
stream = p.open(
    format=FORMAT,
    channels=CHANNELS,
    rate=RATE,
    input=True,
    output=True,
    frames_per_buffer=CHUNK
)

# Creates a figure with two subplots (ax and ax2) for plotting the audio waveform and its FFT. 
# The figsize parameter sets the size of the figure.
fig, (ax, ax2) = plt.subplots(2, figsize=(15,8))

x = np.arange(0, 2 * CHUNK, 2) # Creates an array of x-values for plotting the audio waveform.
x_fft = np.linspace(0, RATE, CHUNK) # Creates an array of frequency values for plotting the FFT.

line, = ax.plot(x, np.random.rand(CHUNK)) # Initializes a line object for plotting the audio waveform in the first subplot (ax).
line_fft, = ax2.plot(x_fft, np.random.rand(CHUNK), '-', lw=2) # Initializes a line object for plotting the FFT in the second subplot (ax2).

ax.set_title('AUDIO WAVEFORM')
ax.set_xlabel('samples')
ax.set_ylabel('volume')
ax.set_ylim(0, 255) #Sets the y-axis limits for the first subplot.
ax.set_xlim(0, 2 * CHUNK) #Sets the x-axis limits for the first subplot.
plt.setp(ax, xticks=[0, CHUNK, 2 * CHUNK], yticks=[0, 128, 255]) #Sets the x and y-axis tick marks for the first subplot.

ax2.set_xlim(20, RATE / 2) # Sets the x-axis limits for the second subplot (FFT plot).


def animate(i):

    data = stream.read(CHUNK) #Reads a chunk of audio data from the audio stream (stream) with a size defined by CHUNK.
    
    # Unpacks the binary data (data) into an array of 8-bit unsigned integers (dtype=np.uint8). 
    # The ::2 slicing selects every other element, effectively downsampling the data to half its
    # original size. It then adds 127 to each element, likely to shift the signal to be centered 
    # around zero.
    data_int = np.array(struct.unpack(str(2 * CHUNK) + 'B', data), dtype=np.uint8)[::2] + 127
    #print("Data before FFT:", data_int[:10]) # Test line
    
    # Computes the Fast Fourier Transform (FFT) of the downsampled audio data (data_int), 
    # resulting in the frequency domain representation of the signal.
    y_fft = fft(data_int)
    print("FFT result:", y_fft[:10]) # Test line
    
    # Updates the y-data of the line object (line) representing the waveform plot to the 
    # downsampled audio data (data_int)
    line.set_ydata(data_int)

    # Normalize FFT data appropriately for plotting
    fft_scaled = np.abs(y_fft[:CHUNK]) * 2 / (256 * CHUNK)

    # Ensure that FFT data is within the expected range
    print("Scaled FFT data:", fft_scaled[:10])

    # Updates the y-data of the line object (line_fft) representing the FFT plot to the 
    # absolute values of the FFT of the first CHUNK elements of y_fft,
    # multiplied by 2 / (256 * CHUNK). 
    # This line is performing scaling and normalization of the FFT data.
    line_fft.set_ydata(fft_scaled)

    # Dynamically adjust y-axis limits of FFT plot
    # Computes the maximum value of the scaled and normalized 
    # FFT data for the first CHUNK elements of y_fft.
    max_fft_value = np.max(np.abs(y_fft[:CHUNK]) * 2 / (256 * CHUNK))
    print("FFT max value: ", max_fft_value)

    # Dynamically adjusts the y-axis limits of the FFT plot (ax2) to 
    # ensure that the highest peak of the FFT is still visible, with some additional padding.
    ax2.set_ylim(0, max_fft_value * 1.2)  # Add some padding

    return line,


ani = animation.FuncAnimation(fig, animate, blit=True, interval=25)

plt.show()

stream.stop_stream()
stream.close()
p.terminate()


Print statement results:
Scaled FFT data: [1.00190353 0.01003554 0.01135945 0.01593705 0.01859334 0.05648837
 0.06349972 0.0216341  0.00649667 0.01902347]
FFT max value:  1.0019035339355469
FFT result: [259594.            -0.j           -526.89172194  -421.1684541j
   -620.77275816  -974.76759017j   -803.61321306 -1479.30911619j
  -1908.98839495 -3732.42741645j  -1478.50360353-12086.16043664j
   5823.63109812+13748.52907801j    753.9622711  +9723.42842246j
   -357.8251014  +5822.08840664j   2099.72688851  -132.28202223j]
Scaled FFT data: [0.99027252 0.00257315 0.00440846 0.00642202 0.0159923  0.04644874
 0.0569575  0.03720328 0.02225141 0.0080257 ]
FFT max value:  0.9902725219726562
FFT result: [259159.            -0.j           -975.66596305  -425.20673075j
   -983.06941718  -971.38178461j  -1768.07764966 -1830.20543882j
   -886.36585775 -3230.9819737j   -2409.68030269 -9523.59742976j
    385.63081796+13794.22263944j   3455.33296729 +6883.58167695j
  -2077.45964916 +4502.06539853j   3222.38202849 +5060.59360891j]
Scaled FFT data: [0.98861313 0.00405996 0.00527203 0.00970745 0.0127806  0.03747452
 0.05264134 0.02938135 0.0189143  0.02288607]
FFT max value:  0.9886131286621094
FFT result: [259411.            -0.j           -736.2249763   +447.79455155j
   -807.77682732  +996.64275809j  -1392.75785217 +1893.07426144j
  -1578.54125986 +3968.1736517j    -531.62002487+10456.14925378j
   3079.24728492 -9764.78184464j  -2633.51543517 -7173.88405137j
   1036.87065086 -4295.54340412j   2347.80102596 -2927.09220684j]
Scaled FFT data: [0.98957443 0.00328717 0.00489383 0.00896535 0.01629112 0.03993856
 0.03905787 0.02915188 0.01685682 0.01431403]
FFT max value:  0.9895744323730469
FFT result: [ 2.60429000e+05-0.00000000e+00j  3.41807755e+02+1.44032065e+00j
  3.65972625e+02-1.00934295e+02j  1.99752000e+02-3.18183525e+02j
  6.38840407e+02+1.69489471e+02j -4.39205486e+03-1.43940023e+03j
 -1.32905659e+04-1.16747241e+04j  1.27824935e+03+4.06302591e+03j
 -1.99573409e+02-4.31481375e+03j -1.28847938e+03+5.15627542e+03j]
Scaled FFT data: [0.99345779 0.0013039  0.0014482  0.00143314 0.00252129 0.01763117
 0.06748223 0.01624815 0.01647731 0.02027445]
FFT max value:  0.9934577941894531

The frequency should be updating along with the time domain plot but this is the result.

Probably everything is plotting as expected. What I am sure about is that you have very large 0 frequency (DC component) value and you are scaling your plot to it.
You can do several things about it:

remove mean of the signal
zero first value of fft which is the mentioned DC component
don't plot (and don't scale to) the first value of fft


You might also convert the y data to dB which should remove issues with ranges.

I see how removing the mean of the signal works but I don't quite understand how it works if you know what I mean. Could you explain how that changes my plot to the correct results? I see if changed it even though it doesn't animate the plot the way it does with the time domain.

@sizzzzlers Very good point! Now that I reread OP question, he works on "spectrum analyser" - decibel scale is mostly used in such a case.

@Skymero You had correct results, just not what you expected. Apart from "regular" sines and frequencies, FFT measures also DC, 0 freuqency, that is basically mean of the signal. You had huge value of the mean and relatively small values of other spectrum components.

would normalizing the data after removing the mean of the signal be redundant? It feels like I'm scaling the data twice

Depends what you exactly mean by term "normalizing", what mathematical operations?

fft_scaled = np.abs(y_fft[:CHUNK]) * 2 / (256 * CHUNK)

I also figured out the animation problem, I needed to change the return line to return line, line_fft

This operation is just scaling, what I suggested is removing mean, completely different operation.
